# WebDriverException: tinyMCE is not defined in selenium web driver java

Tags: java, javascript, selenium

```
driver.switchTo().frame("tinymce_iframe");    
String script="var editor=tinyMCE.get('tinymce_textarea');";    
JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor) driver;    
js.executeScript(script);
```

I want to execute this javascript code but i am getting WebDriverException that tinyMCE is not defined.

```
<html>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce3.5.1/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
       tinyMCE.init({
        theme : "advanced",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        mode : "exact",
        elements : "tinymce_textarea"
      });
     </script>  
      <body>

     <textarea cols="80" rows="10" id="tinymce_textarea" name="tinymce_textarea"> 

         &lt;h1&gt;<span id="1">Article</span> <span id="2">Title</span>&lt;/h1&gt;
         <p><span id="3">Here's</span> <span id="4">some</span> <span id="5">sample</span> <span id="6">text</span> <span id="7">Hello</span> <span id="8" >World.</span> </p>
           </textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the html or the url you are accessing?

Comment: yes, i posted the html

Comment: Is your exception `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error communicating with the remote browser`? Check this post - https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3000.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve using that java script?. As per my understanding your defining a object called `editor` by getting the `textarea` element. Can you post your complete exception details please?

Comment: exception was due to switching to tinymce iframe and then trying to execute javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether you resolved this issue. Here is some ideas to fix issue because I'm not using `tinyMCE` & `Selenium`.

It seems to be a timing issue, while iframe is loading. I am looking into doing an event listener type of thing instead of a timer, but when I wrap my init function, it works properly. I found the hint from this [post here](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=32661):

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', false, 'editorId');
setTimeout(function() {
    tinyMCE.init(myconfig);
}, 3000);
```

Or, if you able to check a proper editor element, then try with `setInterval()`

```
var IntID = setInterval(function () { // Repeated check for Editor
    if (($('.tinymce_textarea').length) > 0) { // Editor element length
        tinyMCE.init({
            theme : "advanced",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
            mode : "exact",
            elements : "tinymce_textarea"
        });
        clearInterval(IntID); // This will clear timer for editor check
    }
}, 10);
```